# best media queries loading styles legacy

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

using the following has loaded all the three css files in my browser and then applied the `medium-device.css` styles

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
media="only screen and (max-width: 480px), 
only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" 
 href="/assets/css/small-device.css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px), 
only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" 
 href="/assets/css/large-device.css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px), 
only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" 
 href="/assets/css/medium-device.css" />
```

this results in loading non-important files and thus increase loading time!

How do I prevent my browser from loading non appropriate css file?

Comment: Here's one idea - http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/